# War in der Vergangenheit der Genitiv nur der gehobenen Sprache "vorbehalten"?

Tags: grammatical-case

Wenn man sich manch einen Text aus dem 19 oder 18 Jh. anschaut, stellt man bald fest, dass die Anzahl der Genitivformen überdurchschnittlich hoch ist oder bestimmt häufiger als heute der Fall ist. *Aus meiner Erfahrung heraus* lassen sich zwei grundlegende Tendenzen erkennen:

1) In der früheren Sprache wurden viel mehr Verben mit dem Genitiv verwendet, etwa *sich erinnern/[Wikipedia](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Diskussion:erinnern#Genitiv)/*, *vergessen/laut Wikipedia "mit Akkusativ, früher und gehoben auch heute noch mit Genitiv"/*, *brauchen/[Hier z.B. wird solche These vertreten](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/brauchen-akkusativ-genitiv.1894997/?hl=de)/* usw.

2) In der heutigen Sprache verwendet man den Genitiv vornehmlich in der [gehobenen Sprache](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gehoben_aufwaerts_erlesen#Bedeutungb) und bei Verben, die gleichsam auf einem absteigenden Ast sind, was ihre Häufigkeit angeht. Beispiele hierfür finden sich in Fülle: *sich befleißigen* *sich entäußern* *sich bemächtigen* usw./ [DWDS zeigt dies am Beispiel von *bemächtigen sehr deutlich*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bem%C3%A4chtigen)

**Deswegen meine Frage:** Wurde in der Vergangenheit der Genitiv nur von der hohen Schicht, sprich, der Obrigkeit, den Dichtern usw. verwendet oder war er den anderen Fällen gleichgestellt und ist aus verschiedenen Gründen im Laufe der Zeit allmählich in den Hintergrund getreten?

**Anmerkung**: Die von mir beschriebenen Tendenzen stehen meines Erachtens nicht zur Debatte, da man sich deren Wahrheitsgehalt ohne weiteres vergewissern kann, indem man zwei Texte aus der Vergangenheit und der Gegenwart miteinander vergleicht oder schlicht die Entwicklung bestimmter Wörter verfolgt.

Comment: Ist (1) und (2) nur eine Annahme von dir oder hast du dazu z.B. statistische Belege?

Comment: Früher wurden auch mehr Krawatten getragen. Besteht da ein Zusammenhang?

Comment: Die Frage wimmelt vor Behauptungen und Fehlannahmen, dass ich gar nicht weiß, wie ich sie beantworten sollte. Ich mag ja insbesondere Texte aus dem 19. Jahrhundert, aber solch eine Feststellung habe ich noch nicht gemacht. Gibt es Quellen zu _jemand habe dessen vergessen_ oder _jemand brauche einer Sache_? Welche Verben sind denn "auf einem absteigenden Ast" und werden mit dem Genitiv gebraucht? Und was ist überhaupt gehobene Sprache? Und gab es hier nicht schon Diskussionen darüber, dass der Dativ nicht unbedingt des Genitivs Tod ist, da es auch Fälle, wo das umgekehrte gilt?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Es kann durchaus sein, dass es auch den umgekehrten Fall gibt, allerdings ist das eher die Ausnahme als die Regel.

Comment: Natürlich steht der Wahrheitsgehalt Deiner Prämissen zur Debatte. Zwei Texte reichen sicher nicht aus, um so eine Behauptung zu überprüfen. Du kannst ja mal einen Text vorlegen mit X Genitiven auf 1000 Wörtern und wir legen dann einen vor mit Y>X Genitiven, der jüngeren Datums ist.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrichIhre Kritik ist berechtigt. Vergessen mit Genitiv gab es aber. Ich werde sehen, ob ich neuere Beispiele finden kann. Ganz alte finden sich im Grimm woraus ich folgendes kopiere:AHD.: Îsegrim sîner smerte vorgat 
unde warp Reinken under sik plat. Reinke de Vos 6363; Hier NHD:das si dadurch vergessen liebes und leides und aller ding. Tauler (1508). Oder: Martinus Luther, ... der nicht allein aller christlichen lieb und evangelischer gottseligkeit vergisset, sondern auch ..; oder: wenn ich gedenck, ich will meiner klage vergessen .. so furchte ich alle meine schmertzen.Hiob 9, 2

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich habe nochmal nachgeschaut. Grimms Beispiele gehen bis ins 19.Jhd. Unter anderem zitiert er Herder (1814) wie folgt: „...von jugend auf dazu eingesegnet wurden, unter den büchern, der welt, des volks, der menschheit zu vergessen.“ Von Goethe zitiert er „ich hatte des kummers völlig vergessen und jeglicher noth. „

Comment: @ludi, interessant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Beobachtung ist richtig. Forschungsstand ist, dass diese - *adverbale* - Genitivverwendung, wie sie in der Frage beschrieben ist, tatsächlich sogar bereits seit ihrer Hochzeit im Mittelhochdeutschen, spätestens seit dem Frühneuhochdeutschen drastisch zurückgegangen ist (sog. Genitivschwund). Das gilt übrigens nicht für andere Verwendungsarten des Genitivs, deren Häufigkeit teilweise gar zugenommen hat.

Wir wissen auch ganz gut, was mit dem adverbalen Genitiv passiert ist: Er ist meist nicht einfach einem anderen Kasus gewichen. Vielmehr kam es zu sog. Valenzwechseln, also etwa - wie im Beispiel der Frage: sich einer Sache erinnern -> sich an eine Sache erinnern.

Zur Ursache: Es gibt hierzu eine Vielzahl von Theorien. Ein wichtiger Faktor dürfte aber - insofern ist die vom Fragesteller aufgeworfene These nicht ganz falsch - darin bestanden haben, dass sich im Zeitverlauf auch die Textsorten geändert haben. Rechts- und gelehrte theologische Texte waren immer schon Tummelplätze für den Objektgenitiv (auch heute noch); dagegen lässt sich für eher volksnahe Texte schon sehr früh nachweisen, dass hier wie in der gesprochenen Sprache eher Konstruktionen mit Akkusativ-/Präpositionalobjekten vorgeherrscht haben. Wenn sich nun also, was der Fall war, die Schriftlichkeit gewissermaßen "geöffnet" hat, dann könnte dies zur Erklärung beitragen.

Zu den (umstrittenen) Einzelheiten gibt es umfangreiche sprachhistorische Literatur; ein paar Stichworte für die weitere Recherche sollten nun ja gegeben sein.

---

*Nachtrag.* Siehe zum Beispiel überblicksartig: Ágel [2000], [Syntax des Neuhochdeutschen bis zur Mitte des 20. Jahrhunderts](https://www.uni-kassel.de/fb02/fileadmin/datas/fb02/Institut_f%C3%BCr_Germanistik/Dateien/syntax_des_neuhochdeutschen_bis_zur_mitte_des_20._jhd_9783110158823.2.13.1855.pdf) (PDF), auf S. 1870-1871, mit zahlreichen Literaturverweisen.

Comment: Man merkt, daß Sie sich auskennen! Aber sind dies nicht zwei verschiedene Fragen (die nach dem Genitivschwund einerseits und die nach den Sprachregistern im Ahd., Mhd. andererseits)? Was man bräuchte wären Beispiele früher Alltagssprache, nicht wahr? Kann man solche finden?

Comment: Vielleicht in diesem Zusammenhang als Marginalie: Wer mit Leuten aus Russland (oder anderen ostslawischsprachigen Gegenden) Kontakt hat, wird feststellen, dass in deren Äußerungen - auch auf Deutsch - der Genitiv auffällig häufig vorkommt. Bis hin zu Ortsbezeichnungen: "Der Platz des Markus", wo gängiges Deutsch vom "Markusplatz" spräche. Klar, das ist eine direkte Übertragung aus dem (z.B.) Russischen. Zeigt aber auch, dass der Genitiv in den ostslawischen Sprachen offenbar auch in der Alltagssprache sich gut behauptet... anders als im Deutschen.